# How to wait to pending promises to return

Tags: javascript, mysql, async-await, mysqljs

Today I was getting so many Promise { < pending > } and I don't know why, so i tried to `console.log()` a few things, and i discovered that getData() is returning before queryDatabase(), can someone explain me why, and what can I do it to fix it? I need queryDatabase() data to return before getData() so the promise doesen't returns pending, here is my code:

(`connection` is a MySQL connection pool)

```js
async function getData(userID, guildID) {
    this.guildID = guildID ?? null
    this.userID = userID ?? null
    this.data = await queryDatabase({guildID: this.guildID, userID: this.userID})
    console.log('foo 2')
    return this.data;
    
}

function queryDatabase(payload) {
    connection.getConnection((sqlerr, con) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            con.query(`(My mysql query)`, (err, rows, fields) => {
                if(err) reject(err);
                con.end()
                resolve(rows[0]);
                console.log('foo')
            })
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Don't use a Promise then. Return the rows instead of a Promise.

Comment: your `function queryDatabase` doesn't return anything since there's no `return` statement

Comment: You put the promise in getConnection instead of queryDatabase.

Comment: Not sure which mysql package you are using but if it doesn't support promises itself there are ones that do. Will simplify that promise wrapping you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue thanks to [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1095495/john), I put the promise in getConnection isntead of queryDatabase, so the function wasn't returning anything, thank you all for the help <3